# How to convert a numeric property of an object in a class to a number and add with other numbers in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, numbers, numerical-methods

I want to add 2 values together at the method in the customer class. one of them is a number and the other is an object property stored in a new class,  the send method(a-b) works well, but the receive method(a+b) doesn't work as a number because it's an object and it is like a string in js, what is the solution?

```
export class Customer {
  constructor(name, password, balance) {
    {
      this.name = name;
      this.password = password;
      this.balance = balance;
    }

    this.send = function (amount) {
      return (this.balance -= amount);
    };
    this.receive = function (amount) {
      return (this.balance += amount);
    };
  }
}

export let student = new Customer("alex", "alex", 200);
export let victim1 = new Customer("tom", "cat", 1000);
export let victim2 = new Customer("jerry", "mous", 500);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: Side note: Rather than assigning traditional functions to properties like `send` and `receive`, I suggest using method syntax so the functions are shared across instances (and so the code is more idiomatic). See [MDN's `class` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#prototype_methods) (or Chapter 4 of my recent book; links in my profile) for details.

Comment: Fantastic!@T.J.Crowder

Answer (score -1):

You can use [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) to convert **amount** to number before use it

```js
class Customer {
  constructor(name, password, balance) {
    {
      this.name = name;
      this.password = password;
      this.balance = balance;
    }

    this.send = function (amount) {
      return (this.balance -= +amount); // magic here
    };
    this.receive = function (amount) {
      return (this.balance += +amount); // and here
    };
  }
}

let student = new Customer("alex", "alex", 200);
let victim1 = new Customer("tom", "cat", 1000);

student.send(victim1.balance);
console.log(student.balance)
student.receive(victim1.balance);
console.log(student.balance)

student.send("500");
console.log(student.balance)
student.receive("100");
console.log(student.balance)
```